# C# Strange timer behaviour

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I have an understanding question concerning timer usage which is not directly connected to erroneous code. It's mor that I#d like to understand what is happening...

I have written a program which one part reads in data from a sensor via COM port and stores it to a variable. This is done using the DataReceivedHandler, so it's done "in the background". Now I need a timer which every second takes the actual values from that variable and does some calculations. The calculation time is about 50-70 msec, so 1 second should be fairly enough time. I tried to work with System.Timer.Timer as well as System.Threading.Timer and both seem to work properly at a first glance, but when I keep my program running for several hours, it starts to stutter - sometimes there is no timer event for seconds, then there are 20 within one (but not every skipped timer event is catched up - many just get lost).
Are the timer events stored in some queue and simply don't get their time slice? As far as I understood, at least System.Threading.Timer should work in an additional thread which prevents from that...

I solved this issue by working with BackgroundWorkers rather than with timers; I created a loop which does my work and then sleeps for (1000 msec - WorkingTime). This works perfectly, so why won't my timers?

Any hint is greatly appreciated!

Comment: MAybe your work function itself stuttered so that lots of events queued up. Make your work function empty and let this run for a few hours. My guess: the problem will be gone. Do you see where I'm getting at?

Comment: Instead of a timer, why not add your data to a property then implement inotifypropertychanged Interface.

Comment: "which is not directly connected to erroneous code." - that's quite a big assumption to make when you're talking about a problem with core components in a framework, and you can't seem to find other people reporting the same issue.

Comment: I do not think I have enough information. When you save your values to a variable, are you using locks as you should? If the calculation time is 50-70ms, it is possible (and more likely) that this calculation time has backed up. Consider this, you may poll the hardware every 20ms and then do a 50ms calculation, leaving yourself with an extra 30ms delay each cycle. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the first replies.

Comment: There are many other events in my program which is starting the timer as it is a GUI. I already cleared my Callback function to the single line outputting the timestamp of the callback start.
When a Threading.Timer fires (regardless if after exactly 1s or 1040ms) there should be a Threadpool.Thread to handle the callback. And the next timer event should be handled by another thread... Is it possible that all threadpool threads were busy? Or does the timer event need to wait for other events in my main function BEFORE it invokes the callback thread?